# Problem with speed of proxies in google cloud

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, cloud, latency, proxies

I have hosted a server in google cloud located in Frankfurt in order to have the lowest possible latency to a web page that is hosted there as well. I have a few German proxies to be able to access that page also with them, but the problem is that I have very high speeds (150ms) using those proxies, when a friend has used them too and has achieved much lower speeds (50ms).

I have 8 cores with 16 GB of ram on the server, but I don't know what the problem is. Is there a google cloud configuration that is making it have such high speeds?

Comment: Most likely you are accessing the endpoint using different network paths. Those paths have different latencies. 150ms is not high. You might have the **last mile** performance problem which means your Internet is slow.

Comment: @JohnHanley but how is it possible that I using googled have more ping than another person using a third party server?

Comment: Edit your question and show the route your network is using, then add their route. CPU performance will have little to zero impact on network latency (ignoring overloaded server conditions).

Comment: @JohnHanley how can i know the route my networking it using? via tracert?

Comment: Yes, tracert is one tool.